# Algolia "Run the crawl from the Docker image"

Tags: algolia

"docker run -it --env-file=.env -e "CONFIG=$(cat ./config.json | jq -r tostring)" algolia/docsearch-scraper" - Getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/src/config/config_loader.py", line 101, in _load_config
    data = json.loads(config, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 367, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/root/src/index.py", line 119, in <module>
    run_config(environ['CONFIG'])
  File "/root/src/index.py", line 33, in run_config
    config = ConfigLoader(config)
  File "/root/src/config/config_loader.py", line 69, in __init__
    data = self._load_config(config)
  File "/root/src/config/config_loader.py", line 106, in _load_config
    raise ValueError('CONFIG is not a valid JSON')
ValueError: CONFIG is not a valid JSON
```

Comment: Fixed by using git bash, windows powershell dont support cat.